# Querying a list

Tags: python, html, django

```
objects = object.objects.values('column name')
```

In HTML, this prints as

> ['column name':"[item1, item2, item3']"}]

Is it possible to access just the elements so rather than the item showing the above in HTML it just shows

> item1 item2 item3

?

Comment: There's really not enough information here to explain how you are using the value within HTML.  If all you are doing is doing the equivalent to print(str(objects)) - that's what you're going to get.  Curtis Olson's answer explains one way to do this (however he doesn't explain why that works), but it would really help if you explained your problem in more detail.

Comment: I think what you are trying to get is the values, for that you need to do objects = object.mymodel.get('mycolumname')

Comment: @eddwinpaz get can only be used for one object.

Comment: use filter() then.

Answer (score 0):

Your queryset returns a list, so you need to iterate over the objects within the list, and also specify which field to print.

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {{ object.column_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Additionally, in your model, you can specify a value to return if you just call `{{ object }}`.

```
class testResult(models.Model):
    # define your model fields here

    def __str__(self): # assuming python 3
        return self.column_name
```

... in which case the first example could be achieved by doing:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
```